# Visual Studio Code Python Intellisense Issue

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Can anyone shed light on why the intellisense isn't work for some imported modules? Example:
[image]

In the above, I'm importing minidom library, but when I do . on the doc object I don't get any code complete options. In the video tutorials I was following, the author was using VSC and they had all the code completion options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your question and after setting `"python.languageServer": "Jedi"` then reloading window, suggestions are showing:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I changed it from the default (pylance) to Jedi and it works for me too. A little bit frustrating that pylance couldn't determine the methods & attributes.

Comment: @RayHogan. You may file a bug report in [microsoft/pylance](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues).